# Django ImageField modelformset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I'm trying to edit a form with a ImageField and I´m using modelformset_factory

in my views :

```
ModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Model, max_num=0,)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Model.objects.filter(pk=2))
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
```

but it doesn´t work, any advice? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean for "doesn't work"?

Comment: That means I can not upload an image when editing a form using using modelformset_factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is fine, just missed placing to put on html tag  enctype="multipart/form-data" on html form...that was the problem